# Display: none in html

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, display

I have this code:

```
   <div id="affichageRecherche"></div>
   <div class="row px-xl-9 d-flex justify-content-start" id="affichageCatalogue">(lot of code)</div>
```

And this script in bottom of the page:

```
<script>
let recherchePieceDetachees = document.getElementById('recherchePieceDetachees');
let affichageRecherche = document.getElementById('affichageRecherche');
let affichageCatalogue = document.getElementById('affichageCatalogue');

        recherchePieceDetachees.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        if(recherchePieceDetachees.value.length > 2){

            affichageCatalogue.style.display = "none";
            fetch('../../requetes/catalogue-piece-detachee.php?recherche='+recherchePieceDetachees.value)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(affichageCatalogue.style.display)
                    
                    affichageRecherche.innerHTML = response;
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
                
        }else{
            affichageCatalogue.style.display = "block";
            affichageRecherche.innerHTML = "";
        }
    });
</script>
```

But when recherchePieceDetachees.value.lenght is > 2 affichageCatalogue.style.display = "none" doesn't work.

In "console display: none is write, but the block is always visible...

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfac.png)

Can somebody help me ?
And sorry for my English... :)
Thanks !

Comment: if i hade some other property to style, it's working...

Comment: is recherchePieceDetachees an input box ? 
I dont see recherchePieceDetachees  in your html

Comment: @Wamiq: Yes it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `d-flex` class in that element. Usually, inline style have highest priority but if a style rule contains `!important`, it will be applied. Bootstrap uses the following code

```
.d-flex{
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Since it have `!important`, it will be applied and your inline style will be ignored.

Inline styles aren't much recommended. You can simply add the class name `d-none` since you are using Bootstrap.

[image]